# Convenções de dlls cdecl e stdcall

Tags: java

Existe diferença nas chamadas das DLLs com as convenções cdecl e stdcall ?

Ou programo do mesmo modo para ambas convenções?

Estou utilizando Java.

Comment: O certo é ddl ou dll?

Comment: dll, tinha escrito errado, já concertei...

Comment: Alguém para ajudar?